# How do I get the response time from a jQuery ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, time, request, response

So I am working on tool that can show long a request to a page is taking.

I am doing this by using jQuery Ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and I want to figure out the best way to get the response time.

I found a thread (http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-get-time-of-ajax-post) which describes using the "Date" in JavaScript, but is this method really reliable?

An example of my code could be this below

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
}).done(function () {
    // Here I want to get the how long it took to load some.php and use it further
});
```

Comment: see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3700307/889678

Comment: Why can't we use chrome developer tool   here in dev tool goto networks-> XHR   You can see all request with there size and time

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The most simple method would be to add `var ajaxTime= new Date().getTime();` before the Ajax call and in the `done` get the current time to calculate how long the Ajax call took to make.

```
var ajaxTime= new Date().getTime();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
}).done(function () {
    var totalTime = new Date().getTime()-ajaxTime;
    // Here I want to get the how long it took to load some.php and use it further
});
```

Or in case of you want to know how long time this take on the server side.
Do the same and print the time in the return value from some.php.

Comment: You can use `Date.now()` instead of the longer `new Date().getTime()`. It doesn't only save characters but also saves creation of a `Date` object.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer Regarding `Date.now()` - it's not available in some older browsers (e.g. IE8), you might need a polyfill, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Comment: downvoting - won't work for multiple requests

Comment: is it Return in milliseconds or Microseconds?