# Script calls from ajax response are executing JQuery ajax prefilter

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to capture timing for ajax requests triggered using jQuery.
For that I defined functions on `jQuery.ajaxPrefilter` and  `options.complete`

`startTime` is set in the function defined for `jQuery.ajaxPrefilter` and when the function defined for `options.complete` is invoked I will set `endTime`.  The difference between `endTime` and `startTime` is my timing for the ajax call.

But somehow when an ajax response comes with HTML that has "script calls", both `jQuery.ajaxPrefilter` and `options.complete` methods are getting invoked.

Why are "script calls" routed through JQuery methods?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763987/how-do-i-get-the-response-time-from-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: I went through given link and it tells how to get timming. I am doing similar thing using "jQuery.ajaxPrefilter" and 
"options.complete" But the issue I am getting is.. when ajax response is an html with script tags.. The script tag requests are also routed through Jqyery methods, this is where problem comes.   So for a single ajax call.. if ajax response has 3 script call in it  then I am getting timings for total 4 calls.. (1 for actual ajax call and other 3 for script call from ajax response)