# Performance testing on Edge using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, microsoft-edge

I am trying to automate my performance testing scenario on two different browser Edge and Chrome, since both scripts supports the JavaScript API's for performance.

The problem I am facing is my scenarios are different from one another, but this happen on the same session of web Browser.

For example, I need to measure the response time on opening a form which is first scenario, the second scenario would be response time taken for a form to save, both are two different scenarios but use same session of browser.

I am trying to use the following code once my first scenario is done

```
window.performance.timing.responseStart - window.performance.timing.responseEnd
```

here I get proper time 8 ms, post this I try to fill and save form which is my second scenario, and verify the response time like the above, I still get 8 ms  which is not validate as the actual time took to save and reload the new form is more than 8 ms. When I check the individual response start and end time, they remain same for the entire session.

I want to calculate different response time for the form on save and reload. Is this feasible in First place? If so what is the better approach?

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming), we can see that:

**PerformanceTiming.responseStart**: When the browser received the first byte of the response, from the server from a cache, or from a local resource.

**PerformanceTiming.responseEnd**: When the browser received the last byte of the response, or when the connection is closed if this happened first, from the server, the cache, or from a local resource.

So, according to above properties we could get the total time taken to download the webpage from the server.

More detail about the process timing, I suggest you check the [PerformanceTiming interface](https://w3c.github.io/navigation-timing/#the-performancetiming-interface) and [Measure Web Page Performance Using JavaScript](http://qnimate.com/measuring-web-page-performance-using-modern-javascript-apis/).

Besides, if you want to calculate the response time for the form save and reload, I suggest you could also try to use Date object to calculate the time, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763987/how-do-i-get-the-response-time-from-a-jquery-ajax-call) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341156/calculating-page-load-time-in-javascript).