# How to resume a client-side timer after browser session is closed?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

Assuming I have a timer which will be activated by user click on a button, How can I save the data (current timer state and data) before user closes his browser and resume the timer after user visits the same page , taking into account the elapsed time between the two sessions.

My development is based on ASP.NET MVC4 and mostly I use ajax calls to service user interactions.

I am considering if there is a way that I can control this interaction and requirement via server-side code but I am skeptical about this.

What is your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do full on client side by using cookies.

Here is the flow:

1. in the click event handler create a timer
2. add event handler for browser close event (look here [How to capture browser close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622461/how-to-capture-browser-close-event-in-javascript))
3. in browser close event handler get remaining time of timer (here you can find instructions [find the time left in a setTimeout()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144711/javascript-find-the-time-left-in-a-settimeout))
4. write a cookie with that information
5. on page load check if there is a cookie with time left info and recreate a timer with remaining time using setTimeout

I will try to update this post asap with more code examples.

**UPDATE**

```
var timeLeft= $.cookies('timeLeft') || ORIGINAL_VALUE;
var timer = setTimeout(myFunc, timeLeft);
$(window).unload(function(){
  var timeLeftToSave = getTimeLeft(timer);
  $.cookies('timeLeft', timeLeftToSave, { path: '/' });
})

//Use code from the second link here
function getTimeLeft(timer){

}



function myFunc(){/*YOUR CODE HERE*/}
```

Comment: Thank you, Perfect answer as far as I see, but lets assume user has disabled cookie or as we know some malicious javascript/app code has disabled the cookie, do you think is there any other way to do the job?

Comment: That's a little bit problematic, but there should be some way, I will let you know once get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a cookie with the current value on the `unload` event and then check for this when you start your timer again?

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    // Set a cookie with current timer value
});
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4825695/1043198) for info on setting cookies in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write some client-side `Javascript` to detect `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` events, and store the timer's value in the user's browser's local storage.

For handling the local storage I would suggest an excellent library: LawnchairJS. 
From the relevant [documentation](http://brian.io/lawnchair/):

> By default, Lawnchair will persist using DOM Storage but if other
>   adapters are available and DOM Storage isn't supported by the
>   currently executing JavaScript runtime. Lawnchair will attempt each
>   successive adapter until it finds one that works.

Comment: I think your solution is a good one but not for every scenarios, I feel it will complicate things and I need to use a 3rth party library besides javascript capabilities itself. If you think I am off about this please , clarify it.

Comment: It all depends on the amount of data you plan to store. If it is just a few bytes, than it is perfectly OK to use cookies.

If you plan to lean more heavily on client-side processing, and more than a few bytes of data will be stored on client's machine, it is often recommended to avoid storing a lot of data in cookies, as they will be sent to server with every request, and this may result in a significant overhead.

Comment: If under "data" in your question you meant storing Date/Time, then it is tiny enough to be stored in cookies.