# Declaring three variables with two values?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

So, I found a function in Stack Overflow a few days ago and I'm trying to understand it because I want to adapt it and apply it to my project. It's a function by Murplyx and it's in the 3rd answer of this question: [find the time left in a setTimeout()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144711/javascript-find-the-time-left-in-a-settimeout/10786331#10786331)

My doubtfulness instantly begins when I start reading the function. The first statement is `var id, started, remaining = delay, running`. What does this mean? Also, why don't any of the statements have a semicolon at the end? The last question is probably dumb but I've always been advised use semicolons because otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: For the `semicolon` part http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
var id, started, remaining = delay, running;
```

is identical to simply

```
var id;
var started;
var remaining = delay;
var running;
```

It's a shorthand to declare multiple variables at once.

As for semicolons, Javascript has something called *automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)*, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi), for example. Not a style I would recommend since it's easy to let in unintentional quirks, but your mileage may vary.