# Detailed cooldown for commands

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I saw in some discord servers that they have a detailed cooldown and that they can exactly see how long it takes before they can use that command again
but I don't know how add this, can someone help me?

I have this now

```
const talkedRecently = new Set();
if (talkedRecently.has(msg.author.id)) {
  msg.channel.send("Wait 1 minute before getting typing this again. - " + msg.author);
} else {
  talkedRecently.add(msg.author.id);
  setTimeout(() => {
    talkedRecently.delete(msg.author.id);
  }, 60000);
}
```

but here you can't see exactly how long you have to wait. I want it like this:
[image: like this]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is not a place to find someone that writes code for you. Instead try to get something to work first and come back when you have a specific code question. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144711/find-the-time-left-in-a-settimeout

Maybe you need to customise the setTimeout according to your needs. Have a look at this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you create an object of cooldowns you can get how much time they would have left by subtracting the date from the cooldown.

Like so:

```
//Start of code or something
var cooldowns = {}
var minute = 60000;
var hour = minute * 24;

//Set cooldown
cooldowns[message.author.id] = Date.now() + hour * 24; //Set a 24 hour cooldown

//At command check
if(cooldowns[message.author.id]){
     if(cooldowns[message.author.id] > Date.now()) delete cooldowns[message.author.id];
     else console.log("user still has " + Math.round((cooldowns[message.author.id] - Date.now)/minute) + " minutes left"
}
```

Comment: Where does I have to add this in the code and how do I add the cooldown to a member

Comment: read the code, it shows you everything. At the top it shows you variables needed. In the middle it shows you how to "set" a cooldown. So you can put this in a specific command or set it every time a message is received. It's all your choice. At the bottom is code how to check if they still have a cooldown or not.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but the simplest way to do this is something like:

```
const talkedRecently = new Set();
const seconds = "60";

loopnum = 0
while (loopnum <= seconds)) {
  loopnum = loopnum + 1;
  if (talkedRecently.has(msg.author.id + "-" + loopnum)) {
    msg.channel.send("Wait **" + loopnum + " **seconds before getting typing this again. - " + msg.author);
    return;
  }
}
loopnum = seconds;
while (loopnum = 0) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (talkedRecently.has(msg.author.id + "-" + (loopnum+1))) {
      talkedRecently.delete(msg.author.id "-" + (loopnum+1));
    }
    talkedRecently.add(msg.author.id + "-" + loopnum);
  }, 1000);
  loopnum = loopnum - 1;
}
if (talkedRecently.has(msg.author.id + "-1")) {
  talkedRecently.delete(msg.author.id "-1");
}
return;
```

Comment: It gives a lot of errors that can't be fixed without manipulating the code